# ktor server - Infinite recursion while introducing timeout on route level

Tags: kotlin, jackson, ktor

I am working on a kotlin `ktor` server based application,  recently I introduced route level timeouts,
I started seeing `Infinite recursion` errors, while searching for the reason I could see it might be related to ordering/relationship between different `coroutines` that is being used, Can someone help over here to go in correct direction , My assumption is timeout is trying to cancel one coroutine and other coroutine is waiting for it indefinitely.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine["children"]->java.util.Collections$SingletonList[0]->kotlinx.coroutines.UndispatchedCoroutine["parent$kotlinx_coroutines_core"]->kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine["children"]->java.util.Collections$SingletonList[0]->kotlinx.coroutines.UndispatchedCoroutine["parent$kotlinx_coroutines_core"]->kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine["children"]->java.util.Collections$SingletonList[0]->kotlinx.coroutines.UndispatchedCoroutine["parent$kotlinx_coroutines_core"]->kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine["children"]->java.util.Collections$SingletonList[0]->kotlinx.coroutines.UndispatchedCoroutine["parent$kotlinx_coroutines_core"]->kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine["children"]->java.util.Collections$SingletonList[0]->kotlinx.coroutines.UndispatchedCoroutine["parent$kotlinx_coroutines_core"]->kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine["children"]->java.util.Collections$SingletonList[0]->kotlinx.coroutines.UndispatchedCoroutine["parent$kotlinx_coroutines_core"]

Comment: "My assumption is timeout is trying to cancel one coroutine and other coroutine is waiting for it indefinitely". I don't see how that would lead to infinite recursion. A timeout or deadlock maybe, but not infinite recursion.

Comment: Also, you will probably get a better answer if you show us the code that leads to this error.